# $ not found error while using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically click a button when it is created and after clicking the button, close the interval. But the following script is giving me `$ is not defined` error. Can anyone help me where am I doing wrong?

```
var timer = setInterval(
    function () { 
        if ($('#element')) { 
            $('#element').click(); 
            clearInterval(timer);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            console.log('Element not found'); 
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be defined?

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? Are you running jQuery in noConflict mode?

Comment: Besides maybe not including jQuery, use a timeout, that one executes once, and no need to clear any intervals nor use if/else statements

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code, but when doing an `if` check on an element make sure to do `if ($('my element').length)` instead because even if the element doesn't exist it returns an array so you need to check if the length of the array contains at least 1 instance of your element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only if you are using jQuery add their cdn in your html page

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: He's using jQuery functions like $(elem).click, so if jQuery isn't included it wouldn't work...not sure what there is to prove...

Comment: I just rechecked the and found the error was due to jQuery not being included as there was a small typo in the 'src' attribute.